# How to enable dropping an element to another browser tab and drop there using cdkDrandAndDrop?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am using angular cdkDragAndDrop to drag and drop elements from one list to another, but I would like to extend my implementation to also enable dragging the element to another tab of the same page and drop it there.
But when I try to drag the element out of my browser tab, it disappears and doesn't move to the next tab.

To make it more clear, a use case example of this behavior is like we can select the url of this page and drag it to next page and drop there.

Comment: You can not. An element only "exist" in his "browser" (a tab is "like" another browser)

Comment: what is the other solution then? @Eliseo , the HTML drag option does allow taking element between browser tabs. Is that the only possibility?